# Get URLs from google image search using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need a text file where each line is a URL to an image from a google search.

I originally found a guide for this when I was watching fastia's courses. However, the javascript they provided for getting the URLs is no longer working. I should probably mention that it used to work for me.

The method that used to work for me, would be to search google.com/images for e.g. "dogs", then scroll down, to load a lot of images. Then press ctrl+shift+J (chrome browser), this will open a console, into which I would paste the following:

```
document.body.innerHTML = `<a href="data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,${escape(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.rg_di .rg_meta')).map(el=>JSON.parse(el.textContent).ou).join('\n'))}" download="links.txt">download urls</a>`;
```

Then after pressing enter, I would get a link to download a text file (links.txt). This file would contain URLs for each image in the previous google search. Jobs done! (this worked for me less than a month ago).

But when I run the code now, I just get an empty file.
I don't know anything about javascripts, so this is close to impossible for me to debug. But I suppose something must have changed, since this is no longer working, but I don't know what that could be. I even tried it on my gf's computer and the result is the same - an empty file.

Here is a link to a similar guide, also inspired by the fastai course. (I can't find the original one I used) https://towardsdatascience.com/fastai-image-classification-32d626da20#d90e

I also tried following this guide and it does not even give me a file or a link. See the result in the image below.
[My result from the linked guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5El8.png).

In my recent search for a solution, I have found multiple guides like this one, but none of them work for me.

I would really appreciate if the solution could be as simple as my previous method, where all I had to do was paste a single line into a console. I imagine that a small change to the previous javascript can make it work again, but I might be wrong...

And yes - I know what the warning in the image says. :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this in console

```
var urls=Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.rg_i')).map(el=> el.hasAttribute('data-src')?el.getAttribute('data-src'):el.getAttribute('data-iurl'));
var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(urls.join('\n'));
hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
hiddenElement.download = 'myFile.txt';
hiddenElement.click();
```